# I saw these strange bee in my garden, and they drag little insect and/or caterpillar to their nest

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: Hornet?]

I saw these strange bee in my garden, and they drag little insect and/or caterpillar to their nest. What are they?
When I catch them by gloves, their body is extremely hard. I notice since a few of my normal honey bee are found dead on the ground. I am in tropical region, is this a type of Asia Hornet? I haven't seen US hornet, so I can't compare, but I felt like these bee are much smaller than the American Hornet for some reason. These bee are either smaller or same size as our Asia honey bee.

Is there anyway I can find the nest? I saw a bunch of small insect near where I saw 1 Asian giant hornet (I am assuming this is a hornet, I will exterminate them regardless, just want to verify if this is indeed Asia Giant Hornet - though this is quite small to be call giant). Is it plausible that where they gather the insect is where their nest is?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more **clear** closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible); 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) habitat information; and 4) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information — also try searching online for "Asian Giant Hornet". ——— Finally, please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Comment: In addition, your question isn't really clear — I'm assuming that what you really want to know is the identity of this insect. If so, please remove the irrelevant parts of your post. Note that "is this dangerous" isn't a good question for this site — it depends on many factors. Is the question: Is this dangerous to humans or some other organism(s)? If to humans, we don't answer personal medical questions and what constitutes "danger"? Anything with mouthparts can bite and that type of insect could be able to sting. Does the person in question have an allergy?

Comment: if you don't have another photo take another picture of that plate with a ruler paid across it, preferably from a similar angle. but yes location will be important.  I also suggest googling "parasitic wasp". behavior wise it seems like a fit.

Comment: where are you located?